# How to free up ram in iOS

Tags: ios, ram

I was wondering if it is possible to free up ram programmatically in iOS? At least I would like to remove all the apps in the background.. thanks..

Comment: I've seen a few of jailbroken Apps that do this such as SBSettings, But no apple store apps.
This makes me think it's something apple restricts, i can't imagine them wanting apps to be able to do this.

Comment: what memory do you want to free up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for this. However, if your app is in the foreground and uses tons of RAM, it will cause the OS to kill background apps, freeing some RAM.

I'm not sure this will get pass the approval process though.

Comment: That, for sure, will get you rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot free up RAM of other applications.  However, this will happen automatically by the OS closing background applications if necessary.

You CAN us the didReceiveMemoryWarning: delegate method to free up memory that is no longer being used in your own classes.

Comment: perhaps i can use `endBackgroundTask` method?

Comment: No, that is not how that method works.  Think of this from Apple's point of view... Apple is normally known for having really good security.  What if an App could kill all other Apps and, essentially, prevent them from ever working because it would just insta-kill them when launched?  Doesn't this sound like a security issue?  It should not come as a surprise that the ability to kill other Apps is not a power Apple gives programmers in iOS.